# Socket.io client in python for distributed app

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, python-asyncio

Do people use socket.io for distributed/network-based apps in python? Not just web apps but traditional client/server (running over http)? I have a flask python web server running socket.io, which is fine, but on the client side it seems there's only https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client which doesn't integrate with async or gevent/eventlet (seems to be all synchronous) so it's hard to use in a production distributed system. What do people use for this kind of communication? Would raw websockets be better?

Comment: Websockets is a protocol designed for communication between web browser and server. If you are building distributed system where several machines need to communicate over the network, then I believe websockets are not the best choice.

Comment: Why not websocket?

Comment: Actually in the modern world of firewalls and proxies, I think websockets are an excellent choice for distributed apps, compared to traditional sockets. What would you suggest instead, @AndriyMaletsky?